# Proxy settings for Google Assistant sdk on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, google-assistant-sdk

I'm trying to run the Python 3 based Google Assistant demo on a Raspberry Pi as a demonstration in school. It works fine at home but not behind the school proxy. It doesn't seem to use the proxy settings in /etc/environment.

Could somebody please suggest what proxy settings it uses, or more generally, what proxy settings Python uses.

And if I go through the student proxy I'll also need to install the proxy's certificate to enable it to inspect https traffic. Where should I put this certificate?

Regards - Philip